# wrong image position in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, picasso

am displaying images on custom listview. images are being fetched from URL. To set these images on imageview am using Picasso. here is its documentation 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

But the problem is that images position is not correctly being displayed. I've searched a lot but couldn't find any sound solution. Picasso is good to load remote images to imageview but I don't know what's problem with my adopter. here is my getview code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.HeadImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.headingimg);
            String url = headingimage.get(position);
                    Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.HeadImage);
            if (position == 0) {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Any help with picasso library or without picasso which'll solve the issue would be very much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.HeadImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.headingimg);

        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        String url = headingimage.get(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.HeadImage);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you are just loading the image each time to the Imageview, which is not effecient

Comment: can you suggest better technique?

Comment: I've also tried this by removing tags but the result is same :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.HeadImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.headingimg);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }String url = headingimage.get(position);
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.HeadImage);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I've also tried this by removing tags but the result is same :(

Comment: without tags there is repetition of entries, how we can stop?